# Angular sqlLite set css url() cannot set relative path

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm using Angular sqlLite within an Ionic (hybrid) app to set the src of an image dynamically. I need to set the css url property to equal this ordinary img declaration:

```
   <img src="/images/img.png"/>
```

However, when set set the src property the DOM shows that this has been resolved into a file:// absolute path, which doesn't render (not sure why, but relative paths render fine).

```
   var loadingImg="images/img.png";
   element.css({
        'src': "url("+loadingImg+")"
      });
```

The DOM shows this rendered as:

```
<img  style="src: url(file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/FD21EBE7-96DE-4DF2-A959-E8ED9C48CC20/Pulsar.app/www/images/bkg/2.png);">
```

How do I set it so that it renders as the relative path I  intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular better to use `ng-src` instead of `src`.

in controller :

```
$scope.loadingImg="images/img.png";
```

and in html:

```
<img ng-src="loadingImg"/>
```

**Updated:**

If you want to use directive to set image then can follow like:

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('setImage', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var loadingImage = 'http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03589/Wellcome_Image_Awa_3589699k.jpg';
      attrs.$set('src', loadingImage);
    }
  };
});
```

and **HTML**:

```
<img  set-image src="default/image.jpg" alt="img" />
```

Comment: Thanks - in this circumstance I need to set the src via the directive's element.

Comment: using directive can use `attrs.$set` I updated my answer :) @metalaureate